# PHP - Calculate "physical" (display) width of string

Tags: php, pdf, graphics, fonts

I am writing PDF based on user input with the FPDF library.  I am using "Arial" as my font throughout the document.  Since I am putting user input into the PDF I can easily overflow the lines thus making it look ugly.  For this reason I would like to know the physical width of a string at a given font size so that I can adjust the XY appropriately and\or reduce the font size and\or drop down to the next line.

For example:

```
 A string of 10 'W's
 WWWWWWWWWW
 is physically longer than
  a string of 10 'l's
 llllllllll
```

WWWWWWWWWW
-vs-
llllllllll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FPDF's `GetStringWidth` [function](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm):

```
$pdf->GetStringWidth($your_string);
```

It returns the length of a string in user unit. A font must be selected.

Comment: @AbtoolKabash Yes, using monospaced fonts is another option.

Comment: @AbtoolKabash: Accept this answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `PDF_stringwidth`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-stringwidth.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing what you want, but a quick Google suggests that the Imagick library has a function which will return the width of a rendered font: [Imagick::queryFontMetrics](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php).